# slick sub-select and join

Tags: mysql, scala, slick-3.0

I have an issue about select from a few tables.

For example I have 3 depending tables and want to select data. 
Uses join approach

```
  val q = tableQ
      .join(t1)
      .join(t2)
      .join(t3)
      //exclude myself
      .filter(el => el._1._2._1.id =!= el._1._1._1.id)
...
```

looks very ugly. Can slick 3 use something like sub queries.

for example

```
tableQ.filter(el => t1.filter(...)).filter(el => t2.filter(...))
```

BR!

Answer (score 0):

Maybe [monadic-joins](http://slick.typesafe.com/doc/3.0.0/queries.html#monadic-joins)

?

```
val monadicInnerJoin = for {
  c <- coffees
  s <- suppliers if c.supID === s.id
} yield (c.name, s.name)
```

You can try something like

```
val monadicInnerJoin = for {
  c <- coffees
  s <- suppliers filter(_.x === y) if(condition)
} yield (c.name, s.name)
```